# 3DES Authentication of Ultralight C Tag with Wrong key

Tags: authentication

I am using reader cr013plus reader with Arduino to read NFC Tags but i am facing strange issue regarding the 3DES ultralight C authentication in order to read data

My current key is uint8_t key = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};//key stored in tag

when i change uint8_t key = {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; //use this key for authentication procedure
But AUTHENTICATION worked with no error.

when uint8_t key = {0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
 AUTHENTICATION not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, finally i found the problem, Basucally issue is with the UltralightC Tags they will authenticate with key containing the next byte of original key. Means all Ultralight C Tags authenticate be changing any byte of the key to next byte

for example if the Keys is (0×22,0×22,0×22,0×22,0×22,0×22,0×22,0×22,0×22,0×22,0×22,0×22,0×22,0×22,0×22,0×22)

their 3des authentication can be done with the above original key and also  with the key by changing any of the byte with 0×22 to 0x23 or changing all of the bytes